# Substructure search with RDKit

Tags: molecular-structure, cheminformatics

I'm trying to search for substructures with RDKit.

I would like to search for structure 1 as substructure in other structures. I don't understand why it doesn't find this structure in structures 3 and 5. I assume this is not a bug in RDKit, but more the result of my limited chemistry understanding. Something with aromaticity? Something wrong with the structures?
Can someone explain to me why it doesn't find structure 1 in structures 3 and 5?
How should the search structure look like that I will find all structures 2-5?

[image]

```
from rdkit import Chem

smiles_list = ['C12=CC=CC=C1C3=CC=CC4=C3C2=CC=C4', 'C12=CC=CC=C1C3=CC=C4C5=C(C=CC2=C35)C6=C4C=CC=C6', 'C12=CC=CC=C1C3=CC=C4C5=C(C=CC2=C35)C=C4', 'C12=CC=CC=C1C3=CC=C4C5=C(C=CC2=C35)C6=C4C=C7CCCCC7=C6', 'C12=CC=CC=C1C3=CC=C4C5=C(C=CC2=C35)C6=C4C=C7CC8=CC=CC=C8CC7=C6']

pattern = Chem.MolFromSmiles(smiles_list[0])
for idx,smiles in enumerate(smiles_list):
    m = Chem.MolFromSmiles(smiles)
    print("Structure {}: pattern found {}".format(idx+1,m.HasSubstructMatch(pattern)))

# Result:
# Structure 1: pattern found True
# Structure 2: pattern found True
# Structure 3: pattern found False
# Structure 4: pattern found True
# Structure 5: pattern found False
```

Comment: thank you for pointing to this. I think I found a solution (see my answer), but I'm not sure if this solution might cause some other surprises or unexpected results. Should I discuss this on the mailing list? What do you think?

Comment: @GeoffHutchison See above response.

Comment: @theozh Just a heads up, if you reply to a comment, you have to tag the person, otherwise, they won't see it. Welcome to Chem.SE! I love your question and will be following it. Very interesting work you're doing.

Comment: I just realized you're not new to chem.se, but welcome anyway! You have some seriously cool questions!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following looks like a solution, unless anybody disproves it. Thank you @Unskilled, for pointing me in the right direction.

If you use structure 1 with `smiles_1a:` `C12=CC=CC=C1C3=CC=CC4=C3C2=CC=C4`, you will not find structures 3 and 5.
If you take OpenBabel and convert `smiles_1a` to SMILES you get: `c12ccccc1c1cccc3c1ccc3`.
If you take this SMILES string and convert it to `mol` via `Chem.MolFromSmarts()` you will find all structures. However, I don't want to use additional external tools.

So, in RDKit, if you convert `smiles_1a` to `mol` and this `mol` back to SMILES again, you get `c1ccc2c(c1)-c1cccc3cccc-2c13`. If you search with this, you will still not find structures 3 and 5. Probably because of the defined single bonds. However, if you replace `-` by `~`, you get `smiles_1b`: `c1ccc2c(c1)~c1cccc3cccc~2c13`. With this, you will find also structures 3 and 5. Happy End, hopefully.

**Code:** (I also added Benzene to have a non-match)

```
from rdkit import Chem

smiles_list = ['C12=CC=CC=C1C3=CC=CC4=C3C2=CC=C4', 'C12=CC=CC=C1C3=CC=C4C5=C(C=CC2=C35)C6=C4C=CC=C6', 'C12=CC=CC=C1C3=CC=C4C5=C(C=CC2=C35)C=C4', 'C12=CC=CC=C1C3=CC=C4C5=C(C=CC2=C35)C6=C4C=C7CCCCC7=C6', 'C12=CC=CC=C1C3=CC=C4C5=C(C=CC2=C35)C6=C4C=C7CC8=CC=CC=C8CC7=C6','c1ccccc1']

def search_structure(pattern):
    for idx,smiles in enumerate(smiles_list):
        m = Chem.MolFromSmiles(smiles)
        print("Structure {}: pattern found {}".format(idx+1,m.HasSubstructMatch(pattern)))

smiles_1a  = smiles_list[0]
pattern_1a = Chem.MolFromSmiles(smiles_list[0])
smiles_1b  = Chem.MolToSmiles(pattern_1a).replace('-','~')
pattern_1b = Chem.MolFromSmarts(smiles_1b)

print("\nSMILES 1a: {}".format(smiles_1a))
search_structure(pattern_1a)
print("\nSMILES 1b: {}".format(smiles_1b))
search_structure(pattern_1b)
```

**Result:**

```
SMILES 1a: C12=CC=CC=C1C3=CC=CC4=C3C2=CC=C4
Structure 1: pattern found True
Structure 2: pattern found True
Structure 3: pattern found False
Structure 4: pattern found True
Structure 5: pattern found False
Structure 6: pattern found False

SMILES 1b: c1ccc2c(c1)~c1cccc3cccc~2c13
Structure 1: pattern found True
Structure 2: pattern found True
Structure 3: pattern found True
Structure 4: pattern found True
Structure 5: pattern found True
Structure 6: pattern found False
```

Answer (score 9):

I'm not sure about why it's not matching but when I carry out substructure matches in rdkit I use SMARTS instead https://www.daylight.com/dayhtml/doc/theory/theory.smarts.html

Here is what I would have done.

```
from rdkit import Chem

smiles_list = ['C12=CC=CC=C1C3=CC=CC4=C3C2=CC=C4', 'C12=CC=CC=C1C3=CC=C4C5=C(C=CC2=C35)C6=C4C=CC=C6', 'C12=CC=CC=C1C3=CC=C4C5=C(C=CC2=C35)C=C4', 'C12=CC=CC=C1C3=CC=C4C5=C(C=CC2=C35)C6=C4C=C7CCCCC7=C6', 'C12=CC=CC=C1C3=CC=C4C5=C(C=CC2=C35)C6=C4C=C7CC8=CC=CC=C8CC7=C6', 'c1ccccc1']

pattern = Chem.MolFromSmarts('[#6]12~[#6][#6]~[#6][#6]~[#6]1[#6]3~[#6][#6]~[#6][#6]4~[#6]3[#6]2~[#6][#6]~[#6]4')
for idx,smiles in enumerate(smiles_list):
    m = Chem.MolFromSmiles(smiles)
    print("Structure {}: pattern found {}".format(idx+1,m.HasSubstructMatch(pattern)))
```

and the output

```
Structure 1: pattern found True
Structure 2: pattern found True
Structure 3: pattern found True
Structure 4: pattern found True
Structure 5: pattern found True
Structure 6: pattern found False
```

I've added a Benzene smiles to show that it's not just matching everything. The SMARTS pattern I made probably could be better I think. I hope this helps anyway.

Comment: Thank you for testing. Interesting. Then I need to check how I can _reliably_ convert SMILES to SMARTS. Why it doesn't work with SMILES? Still a bug in RDKit?

Comment: I'm not sure why it doesn't work with SMILES, I've always used the m.HasSubstructMatch method with SMARTS. But learning SMARTS is pretty easy, its similar to SMILES just follow the link in the answer.

Comment: I just read that a SMILES is also a valid SMARTS expression. But if I use `Chem.MolFromSmarts(smiles)`, all matches are `False`.

Comment: Yes most SMILES patterns are valid SMARTS but the SMARTS pattern 'C12=CC=CC=C1C3=CC=CC4=C3C2=CC=C4' is not the same as '[#6]12~[#6][#6]~[#6][#6]~[#6]1[#6]3~[#6][#6]~[#6][#6]4~[#6]3[#6]2~[#6][#6]~[#6]4'. The [#6] means any carbon atom aromatic or aliphatic while in the first pattern the C means an aliphatic carbon. Since at some point rdkit will make certain carbons in your molecules aromatic it will mean that it will not match. Also ~ means any bond while = in the first pattern is a double bond rdkit will at some point change some of your molecules bonds to aromatic bonds so will not match.

Comment: OK. I see. But how do I get a SMARTS from a SMILES? So far, couldn't find it in RDKit. From SMARTS to Mol and from Mol to SMILES, but not the other way round. OBabel? I wanted to avoid an extra tool. I need to search further.

Comment: I don't know if there is a function of sorts to do this but I literally took the SMILES 'C12=CC=CC=C1C3=CC=CC4=C3C2=CC=C4' then replaced the characters C ->  [#6] and = -> ~ to get '[#6]12~[#6][#6]~[#6][#6]~[#6]1[#6]3~[#6][#6]~[#6][#6]4~[#6]3[#6]2~[#6][#6]~[#6]4'.

Comment: ah... that easy? A simple search&replace? I hope this will also work for more complex structures, heterocylces, etc... I will check and let you know.

Comment: yea for this case but please read through https://www.daylight.com/dayhtml/doc/theory/theory.smarts.html the SMARTS pattern I made is very basic and might match some thing you may not want it to. Once you understand SMARTS you'll be able to make your own patterns that will be specific to the things you want.